# Pandas Missing required dependencies ['numpy']

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

[image]

I am currently following a beginners introduction to machine learning. 
While entering in the command: 
`import pandas as pd` in the python shell in terminal, I get an error reading:

> ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy'].

**I already looked at the other similar question, tried that solution, but still received the same error.**

Comment: install numpy first.

Comment: I did, and receive this: Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages. Then why I try it again, I get the same error.

Comment: I think numpy version is not compatible with pandas.

Comment: Can you `import numpy`? If so, then your pandas is broken

Comment: When I try to, I get this:

Comment: Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Comment: Keyword *Otherwise reinstall numpy*... So, uninstall, then reinstall

Comment: I did, and still does not work. pip uninstall numpy and then pip install numpy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you might be running on a Mac and perhaps using the default system python. For whatever reason you don't have a complete installation. you have `pandas` but not `numpy`. I'm not sure which packages the tutorial you are following uses, but I would recommend installing the [Anaconda python distribution](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) as it includes `pandas`, all its dependencies and much more, including the `scikit-learn` package often used for machine learning.

If you want to know more about installing a Python environment for machine learning on a Mac, there is a good [tutorial](http://machinelearningmastery.com/setup-python-environment-machine-learning-deep-learning-anaconda/) on machinelearningmastery.com.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't have anything to do with incompatibility.  As @Peter mentioned, you simply don't have NumPy and should install through Anaconda.  Here is the code within pandas that is giving you the error:

```
# Let users know if they're missing any of our hard dependencies
hard_dependencies = ("numpy", "pytz", "dateutil")
missing_dependencies = []

for dependency in hard_dependencies:
    try:
        __import__(dependency)
    except ImportError as e:
        missing_dependencies.append(dependency)

if missing_dependencies:
    raise ImportError("Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
del hard_dependencies, dependency, missing_dependencies
```

Notice there is nothing here about version.

Comment: Yup I wasn't using anaconda but now it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem. I don't know what is the cause of the problem, but it seems to deal with how numpy is installed. You can try the following:

1. Install pandas
2. Uninstall numpy
3. Download numpy whl for your needs from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)
4. Install numpy from downloaded whl

That worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error message with my Anaconda installation when I forget to activate the environment:

Testcode: import_pandas.py:

```
import pandas
print('Pandas import succeeded!')
```

Run import_pandas.py with ImportError:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.1146]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\peter\demo>python import_pandas.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "import_pandas.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas
  File "C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

However, after activating conda everything works perfectly fine:

```
C:\Users\peter\demo>activate
C:\Users\peter\demo>conda.bat activate

(base) C:\Users\peter\demo>python import_pandas.py
Pandas import succeeded!
```